Error when try to map entities in Dapper(Multi-map error: splitOn column)
Error:
System.ArgumentException: Multi-map error: splitOn column 'Id' was not found - please ensure your splitOn parameter is set and in the correct order (Parameter 'splitOn').
It happens when i use check IdentityRoles on Administrator role. If you remove all the checks and all the logic about this, then everything starts to work. See examples below.
Code of GetTransportationRequestQueryHandler:
internal sealed class GetTransportationRequestQueryHandler
    : IQueryHandler<GetTransportationRequestQuery, IReadOnlyList<GetTransportationRequestResponse>>
{
    private readonly ISqlConnectionFactory _sqlConnectionFactory;

    public GetTransportationRequestQueryHandler(ISqlConnectionFactory sqlConnectionFactory)
    {
        _sqlConnectionFactory = sqlConnectionFactory;
    }

    public async Task<Result<IReadOnlyList<GetTransportationRequestResponse>>> Handle(
        GetTransportationRequestQuery request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        string sqlString =
               """
               SELECT
                   a.id AS Id,
                   a.created_by AS CreatedBy, 
                   a.created_on_utc AS CreatedOnUtc,
                   a.last_modified_date_on_utc AS LastModifiedDateOnUtc,
                   a.last_modified_by AS LastModifiedBy,
                   a.type_of_request AS TypeOfRequest,
                   a.customs_clearance AS CustomsClearance,
                   a.delivery_conditions AS DeliveryConditions,
                   a.cargo_readiness_period AS CargoReadinessPeriod,
                   a.deadline_for_submitting_commercial_offer AS DeadlineForSubmittingCommercialOffer,
                   a.type_of_cargo AS TypeOfCargo,
                   a.type_of_packaging AS TypeOfPackaging,
                   a.container_type AS ContainerType,
                   a.places_in_container AS PlacesInContainer,
                   a.loading_in_one_container_net AS LoadingInOneContainerNeT,
                   a.number_of_containers AS NumberOfContainers,
                   a.weight_of_one_place AS WeightOfOnePlace,
                   a.loading_per_container_gross_ton AS LoadingPerContainerGrossTon,  
                   a.port_of_shipment AS PortOfShipment,
                   a.transshipment_port AS TransshipmentPort,
                   a.place_of_delivery AS PlaceOfDelivery,
                   a.cargo_pickup_address AS CargoPickupAddress,
                   a.note AS Note,
                   a.is_visible AS IsVisible,
                   a.index AS Index
               FROM transportation_request AS a
               """;

        if (!request.IdentityUser.IdentityRoles.Contains("Administrator"))
        {
            var firstIndexOfWord = IndexOfFirstLetter(sqlString, "a.created_by");
            var lastIndexOfWord = IndexOfLastLetter(sqlString, "LastModifiedBy,\r\n    ");
            sqlString = sqlString.Remove(firstIndexOfWord, lastIndexOfWord - firstIndexOfWord);
        }

        using var connection = _sqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection();

        var transportationRequestResponse = await connection.QueryAsync<GetTransportationRequestResponse>(
            sqlString,
            new[]
            {
                typeof(Guid),
                request.IdentityUser.IdentityRoles.Contains("Administrator") ? null : typeof(Audit),
                typeof(TypeOfRequest),
                typeof(LogisticsProcess),
                typeof(CargoCharacteristics),
                typeof(CharacteristicsOfTheContainer),
                typeof(LogisticsHubs),
                typeof(string),
                typeof(bool),
            },
            objects =>
            {
                Guid id = (Guid)objects[0];
                Audit? audit = (Audit)objects[1];
                TypeOfRequest typeOfRequest = (TypeOfRequest)objects[2];
                LogisticsProcess logisticsProcess = (LogisticsProcess)objects[3];
                CargoCharacteristics cargoCharacteristics = (CargoCharacteristics)objects[4];
                CharacteristicsOfTheContainer characteristicsOfTheContainer = (CharacteristicsOfTheContainer)objects[5];
                LogisticsHubs logisticsHubs = (LogisticsHubs)objects[6];
                string note = (string)objects[7];
                bool isVisible = (bool)objects[8];

                GetTransportationRequestResponse getTransportationRequestResponse = new(
                id,
                audit,
                typeOfRequest,
                logisticsProcess,
                cargoCharacteristics,
                characteristicsOfTheContainer,
                logisticsHubs,
                note,
                isVisible);

                return getTransportationRequestResponse;
            },
            splitOn: $"Id{(request.IdentityUser.IdentityRoles.Contains("Administrator") ? ",CreatedBy," : ",")}TypeOfRequest,CustomsClearance,TypeOfCargo,ContainerType,PortOfShipment,Note,IsVisible");         
           

        return transportationRequestResponse.ToList();
    }`

Code of IndexOfFirstLetter method:
int IndexOfFirstLetter(string str, string word)
{
    var stringCharArray = str.ToCharArray();
    var wordCharArray = word.ToCharArray();

    int wordLength = wordCharArray.Length;
    int wordIndex = 0;
    int coincidenceCounter = 0;
    int tmpValueForWordIndex = 0;
    int counterForWhile = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < stringCharArray.Length; i++)
    {
        while (counterForWhile < wordLength)
        {
            if (stringCharArray[i] == wordCharArray[counterForWhile])
            {
                tmpValueForWordIndex = i;
                ++coincidenceCounter;
                counterForWhile++;

                if (coincidenceCounter == wordLength)
                {
                    wordIndex = tmpValueForWordIndex - (wordLength - 1);
                }
                break;
            }
            if (stringCharArray[i] != wordCharArray[counterForWhile])
            {
                coincidenceCounter = 0;
                counterForWhile = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return wordIndex;
}

Code of IndexOfLastLettermethod:
int IndexOfLastLetter(string str, string word)
{
    var stringCharArray = str.ToCharArray();
    var wordCharArray = word.ToCharArray();

    int wordLength = wordCharArray.Length;
    int wordIndex = 0;
    int coincidenceCounter = 0;
    int tmpValueForWordIndex = 0;
    int counterForWhile = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < stringCharArray.Length; i++)
    {
        while (counterForWhile < wordLength)
        {
            if (stringCharArray[i] == wordCharArray[counterForWhile])
            {
                tmpValueForWordIndex = i;
                ++coincidenceCounter;
                counterForWhile++;

                if (coincidenceCounter == wordLength)
                {
                    wordIndex = tmpValueForWordIndex;
                }

                break;
            }
            if (stringCharArray[i] != wordCharArray[counterForWhile])
            {
                coincidenceCounter = 0;
                counterForWhile = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return wordIndex;
}

This piece of code removes part of the sql line if there is no administrator role.
if (!request.IdentityUser.IdentityRoles.Contains("Administrator"))
{
    var firstIndexOfWord = IndexOfFirstLetter(sqlString, "a.created_by");
    var lastIndexOfWord = IndexOfLastLetter(sqlString, "LastModifiedBy,\r\n    ");
    sqlString = sqlString.Remove(firstIndexOfWord, lastIndexOfWord - firstIndexOfWord);
}

After deleting the sql line looks like this and this sql query is correct:
SELECT
    a.id AS Id,
     a.type_of_request AS TypeOfRequest,
    a.customs_clearance AS CustomsClearance,
    a.delivery_conditions AS DeliveryConditions,
    a.cargo_readiness_period AS CargoReadinessPeriod,
    a.deadline_for_submitting_commercial_offer AS DeadlineForSubmittingCommercialOffer,
    a.type_of_cargo AS TypeOfCargo,
    a.type_of_packaging AS TypeOfPackaging,
    a.container_type AS ContainerType,
    a.places_in_container AS PlacesInContainer,
    a.loading_in_one_container_net AS LoadingInOneContainerNeT,
    a.number_of_containers AS NumberOfContainers,
    a.weight_of_one_place AS WeightOfOnePlace,
    a.loading_per_container_gross_ton AS LoadingPerContainerGrossTon,  
    a.port_of_shipment AS PortOfShipment,
    a.transshipment_port AS TransshipmentPort,
    a.place_of_delivery AS PlaceOfDelivery,
    a.cargo_pickup_address AS CargoPickupAddress,
    a.note AS Note,
    a.is_visible AS IsVisible,
    a.index AS Index
FROM transportation_request AS a

{
    "records": [
        {
            "id": "872e32ac-cbe7-4d7d-8365-b6b1b4505968",
            "typeofrequest": 1,
            "customsclearance": "string",
            "deliveryconditions": "string",
            "cargoreadinessperiod": "2024-07-16",
            "deadlineforsubmittingcommercialoffer": "2024-07-16",
            "typeofcargo": "string",
            "typeofpackaging": "string",
            "containertype": "string",
            "placesincontainer": 123,
            "loadinginonecontainernet": 23,
            "numberofcontainers": 14,
            "weightofoneplace": 2,
            "loadingpercontainergrosston": 12,
            "portofshipment": "string",
            "transshipmentport": "string",
            "placeofdelivery": "string",
            "cargopickupaddress": "string",
            "note": "string",
            "isvisible": "0",
            "index": 1
        },
        {
            "id": "d9e12d31-f719-48f0-a29c-d64ea54d0af8",
            "typeofrequest": 1,
            "customsclearance": "string",
            "deliveryconditions": "string",
            "cargoreadinessperiod": "2024-07-16",
            "deadlineforsubmittingcommercialoffer": "2024-07-16",
            "typeofcargo": "string",
            "typeofpackaging": "string",
            "containertype": "string",
            "placesincontainer": 123,
            "loadinginonecontainernet": 23,
            "numberofcontainers": 14,
            "weightofoneplace": 2,
            "loadingpercontainergrosston": 12,
            "portofshipment": "string",
            "transshipmentport": "string",
            "placeofdelivery": "string",
            "cargopickupaddress": "string",
            "note": "string",
            "isvisible": "0",
            "index": 2
        },
        {
            "id": "e42d9993-3410-4a41-9ee9-7a1ce5791776",
            "typeofrequest": 1,
            "customsclearance": "string",
            "deliveryconditions": "string",
            "cargoreadinessperiod": "2024-07-16",
            "deadlineforsubmittingcommercialoffer": "2024-07-16",
            "typeofcargo": "string",
            "typeofpackaging": "string",
            "containertype": "string",
            "placesincontainer": 123,
            "loadinginonecontainernet": 23,
            "numberofcontainers": 14,
            "weightofoneplace": 2,
            "loadingpercontainergrosston": 12,
            "portofshipment": "string",
            "transshipmentport": "string",
            "placeofdelivery": "string",
            "cargopickupaddress": "string",
            "note": "string",
            "isvisible": "0",
            "index": 4
        },
        {
            "id": "39cbdfff-79d7-41d6-938d-10071552fd1b",
            "typeofrequest": 1,
            "customsclearance": "string",
            "deliveryconditions": "string",
            "cargoreadinessperiod": "2024-07-16",
            "deadlineforsubmittingcommercialoffer": "2024-07-16",
            "typeofcargo": "string",
            "typeofpackaging": "string",
            "containertype": "string",
            "placesincontainer": 123,
            "loadinginonecontainernet": 23,
            "numberofcontainers": 14,
            "weightofoneplace": 2,
            "loadingpercontainergrosston": 12,
            "portofshipment": "string",
            "transshipmentport": "string",
            "placeofdelivery": "string",
            "cargopickupaddress": "string",
            "note": "string",
            "isvisible": "0",
            "index": 5
        },
        {
            "id": "6b1285f5-e554-458d-9d23-f3180538a548",
            "typeofrequest": 1,
            "customsclearance": "string",
            "deliveryconditions": "string",
            "cargoreadinessperiod": "2024-07-16",
            "deadlineforsubmittingcommercialoffer": "2024-07-16",
            "typeofcargo": "string",
            "typeofpackaging": "string",
            "containertype": "string",
            "placesincontainer": 123,
            "loadinginonecontainernet": 23,
            "numberofcontainers": 14,
            "weightofoneplace": 2,
            "loadingpercontainergrosston": 12,
            "portofshipment": "string",
            "transshipmentport": "string",
            "placeofdelivery": "string",
            "cargopickupaddress": "string",
            "note": "string",
            "isvisible": "0",
            "index": 6
        },
        {
            "id": "c5945a77-5e7f-476a-9645-fa860de0bd46",
            "typeofrequest": 1,
            "customsclearance": "string",
            "deliveryconditions": "string",
            "cargoreadinessperiod": "2024-07-16",
            "deadlineforsubmittingcommercialoffer": "2024-07-16",
            "typeofcargo": "string",
            "typeofpackaging": "string",
            "containertype": "string",
            "placesincontainer": 123,
            "loadinginonecontainernet": 23,
            "numberofcontainers": 14,
            "weightofoneplace": 2,
            "loadingpercontainergrosston": 12,
            "portofshipment": "string",
            "transshipmentport": "string",
            "placeofdelivery": "string",
            "cargopickupaddress": "string",
            "note": "string",
            "isvisible": "0",
            "index": 7
        },
        {
            "id": "4697e6d1-64cc-4df0-b2f8-60666e3cd462",
            "typeofrequest": 1,
            "customsclearance": "string",
            "deliveryconditions": "string",
            "cargoreadinessperiod": "2024-07-16",
            "deadlineforsubmittingcommercialoffer": "2024-07-16",
            "typeofcargo": "string",
            "typeofpackaging": "string",
            "containertype": "string",
            "placesincontainer": 123,
            "loadinginonecontainernet": 23,
            "numberofcontainers": 14,
            "weightofoneplace": 2,
            "loadingpercontainergrosston": 12,
            "portofshipment": "string",
            "transshipmentport": "string",
            "placeofdelivery": "string",
            "cargopickupaddress": "string",
            "note": "string",
            "isvisible": "0",
            "index": 8
        },
        {
            "id": "11132681-ad4e-4b48-90a0-5d48cffd9580",
            "typeofrequest": 1,
            "customsclearance": "string",
            "deliveryconditions": "string",
            "cargoreadinessperiod": "2024-07-16",
            "deadlineforsubmittingcommercialoffer": "2024-07-16",
            "typeofcargo": "string",
            "typeofpackaging": "string",
            "containertype": "string",
            "placesincontainer": 123,
            "loadinginonecontainernet": 23,
            "numberofcontainers": 14,
            "weightofoneplace": 2,
            "loadingpercontainergrosston": 12,
            "portofshipment": "string",
            "transshipmentport": "string",
            "placeofdelivery": "string",
            "cargopickupaddress": "string",
            "note": "string",
            "isvisible": "0",
            "index": 9
        }
    ]
}

As I already said, if you remove the logic of checking for the administrator role, then everything will work.
Then i get response like this:
    {
        "id": "872e32ac-cbe7-4d7d-8365-b6b1b4505968",
        "audit": {
            "createdBy": "0b429df5-bc7f-4291-ae6f-d928c7df6368",
            "createdOnUtc": "2024-07-19T07:14:44.711343Z",
            "lastModifiedDateOnUtc": null,
            "lastModifiedBy": null
        },
        "typeOfRequest": 1,
        "logisticsProcess": {
            "customsClearance": "string",
            "deliveryConditions": "string",
            "cargoReadinessPeriod": "2024-07-16",
            "deadlineForSubmittingCommercialOffer": "2024-07-16"
        },
        "cargoCharacteristics": {
            "typeOfCargo": "string",
            "typeOfPackaging": "string"
        },
        "characteristicsOfTheContainer": {
            "containerType": "string",
            "placesInContainer": 123,
            "loadingInOneContainerNet": 23,
            "numberOfContainers": 14,
            "weightOfOnePlace": 2,
            "loadingPerContainerGrossTon": 12
        },
        "logisticsHubs": {
            "portOfShipment": "string",
            "transshipmentPort": "string",
            "placeOfDelivery": "string",
            "cargoPickupAddress": "string"
        },
        "note": "string",
        "isVisible": false
    },

Please help me understand what I'm doing wrong
I looked at many topics on this issue and did not find an answer.

The problem was in Type[] array:
new[]
{
  typeof(Guid),
  typeof(Audit),
  typeof(TypeOfRequest),
  typeof(LogisticsProcess),
  typeof(CargoCharacteristics),
  typeof(CharacteristicsOfTheContainer),
  typeof(LogisticsHubs),
  typeof(string),
  typeof(bool),
}

If the role is not an administrator, then I delete a piece of sql line that requests CreatedBy, CreatedOnUtc, LastModifiedDateOnUtc, LastModifiedBy, in other words, the Audit object. Accordingly, the sql query returns data without Audit data, but Type[] has typeof(Audit) and it needs to be filled out. And there’s nothing to fill out.
new[]
{
  typeof(Guid),
  typeof(Audit),
  ....
}

This is what caused the error. Refactored code below:
public async Task<Result<IReadOnlyList<GetTransportationRequestResponse>>> Handle(
    GetTransportationRequestQuery request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var isRoleAdministrator = request.IdentityUser.IdentityRoles.Contains("Administrator");

    var sqlString =
           """
           SELECT
               a.id AS Id,
               a.created_by AS CreatedBy, 
               a.created_on_utc AS CreatedOnUtc,
               a.last_modified_date_on_utc AS LastModifiedDateOnUtc,
               a.last_modified_by AS LastModifiedBy,
               a.type_of_request AS TypeOfRequest,
               a.customs_clearance AS CustomsClearance,
               a.delivery_conditions AS DeliveryConditions,
               a.cargo_readiness_period AS CargoReadinessPeriod,
               a.deadline_for_submitting_commercial_offer AS DeadlineForSubmittingCommercialOffer,
               a.type_of_cargo AS TypeOfCargo,
               a.type_of_packaging AS TypeOfPackaging,
               a.container_type AS ContainerType,
               a.places_in_container AS PlacesInContainer,
               a.loading_in_one_container_net AS LoadingInOneContainerNeT,
               a.number_of_containers AS NumberOfContainers,
               a.weight_of_one_place AS WeightOfOnePlace,
               a.loading_per_container_gross_ton AS LoadingPerContainerGrossTon,  
               a.port_of_shipment AS PortOfShipment,
               a.transshipment_port AS TransshipmentPort,
               a.place_of_delivery AS PlaceOfDelivery,
               a.cargo_pickup_address AS CargoPickupAddress,
               a.note AS Note,
               a.is_visible AS IsVisible,
               a.index AS Index
           FROM transportation_request AS a
           """;

    List<Type> getTransportationRequestResponseTypes = 
    [
        typeof(Guid),
        typeof(Audit),
        typeof(TypeOfRequest),
        typeof(LogisticsProcess),
        typeof(CargoCharacteristics),
        typeof(CharacteristicsOfTheContainer),
        typeof(LogisticsHubs),
        typeof(string),
        typeof(bool)
    ];

    if (!isRoleAdministrator)
    {
        var firstIndexOfWord = IndexOfFirstLetter(sqlString, "a.created_by");
        var lastIndexOfWord = IndexOfLastLetter(sqlString, "LastModifiedBy,\r\n    ");

        sqlString = sqlString.Remove(firstIndexOfWord, lastIndexOfWord - firstIndexOfWord);

        getTransportationRequestResponseTypes.RemoveAt(1); //1 is an index of Audit type
    }

    using var connection = _sqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection();

    var transportationRequestResponse = await connection.QueryAsync<GetTransportationRequestResponse>(
        sqlString,
        getTransportationRequestResponseTypes.ToArray(),
        objects => 
        {
            Guid id = (Guid)objects[0];
            Audit? audit = isRoleAdministrator ? (Audit)objects[1] : null;
            TypeOfRequest typeOfRequest = (TypeOfRequest)objects[^7];
            LogisticsProcess logisticsProcess = (LogisticsProcess)objects[^6];
            CargoCharacteristics cargoCharacteristics = (CargoCharacteristics)objects[^5];
            CharacteristicsOfTheContainer characteristicsOfTheContainer = (CharacteristicsOfTheContainer)objects[^4];
            LogisticsHubs logisticsHubs = (LogisticsHubs)objects[^3];
            string note = (string)objects[^2];
            bool isVisible = (bool)objects[^1];

            GetTransportationRequestResponse getTransportationRequestResponse = new(
                id,
                audit,
                typeOfRequest,
                logisticsProcess,
                cargoCharacteristics,
                characteristicsOfTheContainer,
                logisticsHubs,
                note,
                isVisible);

            return getTransportationRequestResponse;
        },

        splitOn: $"Id{(isRoleAdministrator ? ",CreatedBy," : ",")}TypeOfRequest,CustomsClearance,TypeOfCargo,ContainerType,PortOfShipment,Note,IsVisible");


    return transportationRequestResponse.ToList();
}

I simply made a List and filled it based on isRoleAdministrator and filled it with the necessary types.

SplitOn is splitting the single row data into multiple objects, based on a column names you give into it. Exception says it well what is happening.
The reason of the exception you is that you dont have the column CreatedBy in the sql query you posted and marked as correct.
Also, its the same reason why if you remove a logic with Administrator it works well, because- there is no CreatedBy column in your splitOn then, nor in your data that you are trying to split.

The thing is that I don't need the CreatedBy, CreatedOnUtc, LastModifiedDateOnUtc, LastModifiedBy column. If the role is not an administrator, that is, I do not need the Audit object, which I set to null with this line request.IdentityUser.IdentityRoles.Contains("Administrator") ? null : typeof(Audit). And that's why I delete part of the sql line

@keks01 but either i dont understand you, or you dont understood me.
How splitOn is supposed to split a row, if CreatedBy column is not in the data?
If you want to do so, you should prepare two SQL queries. One containing CreatedBy, and another not.

but in this case splitOn also doen't have CreatedBy for spliting, this is achieved by the ternary operator  like this (request.IdentityUser.IdentityRoles.Contains("Administrator") ? ",CreatedBy," : ","))

it doesnt make any sense. If you say when you remove it, it works, means that the condition is somehow fulfilled, and it puts CreatedBy into splitOn. There is no other way it could be broken.

if set  "Administrator" role everything works fine. But if the query doesn't contain "Administrator" role then i remove piece of sql string where requests  Audit data  also i remove CreatedBy from splitOn string. As a result, the sql request does not contain CreatedBy, CreatedOnUtc, LastModifiedDateOnUtc, LastModifiedBy, in other words, Audit data. splitOn also does not have a CreatedBy column for splitting; the splitOn string looks like: $"Id,TypeOfRequest...

@keks01 if its true, im afraid i cant help you more about this topic. It should work.

Any way thanks for help
